# Not understanding Python module in a special case where PYTHONPATH is set to a subdirectory

Tags: python, module, python-import

I encountered an issue I am confused about with Python modules. I have built a minimal working example:

```
$ tree

├── app
│   ├── configuration.py
│   ├── error_code.py
└── test.py
```

app/configuration.py

```py
from error_code import ErrorCode

class Configuration:
    def status(self):
        return self._status

    def __init__(self):
        self._status = ErrorCode.Error1
```

app/error_code.py

```
import enum

class ErrorCode(enum.Enum):
    Success = 0
    Error1 = 1
```

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from app.configuration import Configuration
from app.error_code import ErrorCode

c = Configuration()

print(c.status())
print(c.status() == ErrorCode.Error1)
```

Command: `PYTHONPATH=app ./test.py`

Output:

```
ErrorCode.Error1
False
```

Why does in such case the output show `ErrorCode.Error1` while it says `False` for the equal check?

I suppose it has to do with the module, because if in app/configuration.py I replace `from error_code import ErrorCode` with `from app.error_code import ErrorCode` it works as expected. But it seems weird to me.

Where should I look to get the documentation for this specific behavior?

Comment: It seems to me that the class definition of `ErrorCode` is executed twice in this example, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the directory that `test.py` is in is *also* added to the import path. Which is why this import in test.py worked to begin with:

```
from app.error_code import ErrorCode
```

However, when you do:

```
from error_code import ErrorCode
```

in `app/configuration.py` it relied on `PYTHONPATH=app/`. But the original import was cached as `"app.error_code"` in `sys.modules`, so when you import `error_code` it isn't found in the cache, because it would need to exist as `"error_code"`, and it isn't recognized as the same module, so it is reimported as a new module. IMO, you should use:

```
from app.error_code import ErrorCode
```

And as you noted, the import will be appropriately cached. Really, it's the parent directory of `app` that should be added to the PYTHONPATH to begin with. Better yet, you shouldn't be relying on the working directory or on `PYTHONPATH`, and just make your project pip installable.

Comment: What do you mean by "just make your project pip installable" ?

Comment: @MichelPeseur I mean package your project and install it with `pip`,  probably in editable mode